# angular variable initialization

Tags: javascript, angularjs, sails.js

I have a variable in angular controller, $scope.abc.

I have Sails as backend.

$scope.abc's initial value can be determined by backend when generating the page. After the page is displayed to user, $scope.abc may or may not be changed by the user.

I can have backend to generate a complete static page and let angular query the backend for initial value of $scope.abc. I feel it is not necessary as the initial value can be determined at the page's generation and should come as part of the page.

The question is: how to initialize $scope.abc when the webpage is being generated? Is there any way to provide data to angular js file, similar to res.view("",data)?

Comment: simply make $http from angular controller and assign $scope.abc from it

Comment: does using $http require angular to make a second http request to backend to initialize $scope.abc?

Comment: No need to issue one more request if you already have data.

Answer (score 3):

You don't really have many options here. You can issue one more ajax request and load data. However it my be not ideal if during index page loading the data is already available. In this case you can inject it into additional script tag and access it from from there.

```
<script>
    // Make sure data is JSON encoded.
    window.appConfig = <%= data %>;
</script>
<script src="angular.js"></script>
<script src="app.js"></script>
```

And then I would set a constant service in the app to store data in it:

```
angular.module('app').constant('appConfig', {data: window.appConfig});
```

This way you could use it later in more Angular way, for example:

```
angular.module('app').controller(function($scope, appConfig) {
    $scope.config = appConfig.data.userId;
});
```

And if you are concerned with presence of the global variable `appConfig`, you can remove it in app run block, when constant is already set.