# AngularJS: accessing scope variables in $routeProvider

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, ngroute, ng-init

I have an angular app on a JSP page that has:

```
ng-init="role='<%=String.valueOf(session.getAttribute("role"))%>'"
```

So the body tag will look like this when the JSP pulls the role attribute from the session:

```
<body ng-app="appName" ng-init="role='roleName'">
```

I want to access this `role` variable in the `$routeProvider`.

I tried doing so by passing `$scope` to the `app.config` function as such:

```
app.config(['$routeProvider', '$scope',
    function ($routeProvider, $scope) {
        $routeProvider
        .when('somePath' {
            ...
        })
        .when('someOtherPath' {
            ...
        })
        .otherwise({
            redirectTo: $scope.role == 'goodRole' ? 'somePath' : 'someOtherPath'
        });
}]);
```

However, it appears that you cannot pass in the `$scope` that way.

Is there a way to access a scope variable in this fashion, or is there another way to accomplish this?

Comment: You can't access the $scope  out of a controller or directive link function.

Comment: If it is about authentication role, you can attach variable to a route like [authenticate:true](https://github.com/DaftMonk/generator-angular-fullstack/blob/master/app/templates/client/app/account(auth)/account(js).js), can [redirect](https://github.com/DaftMonk/generator-angular-fullstack/blob/master/app/templates/client/app/app(js).js) to /login page in app.run method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope, it is not possible. How about you set it to a `data-role` attribute and get it from `document.body.dataset.role`:

`data-role="<%=String.valueOf(session.getAttribute("role"))%>"`

Comment: This worked for me, but I'm curious if this is the <air quote>proper</air quote> way to do this.

Comment: Seems like the only possible currently.

Comment: @AndrewMairose I like your <air quote></air quote> :)

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not possible like you are trying, because [configuration phase](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/module) (services are created and configured) takes place *before* run phase (controllers run, directives rendered, scopes linked).

in your case you will probably want to create global variable and access it from config block. In this case you don't have many options really.

Also check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27806879/949476) I provided on the somewhat similar topic about injecting global variable configuration into Angular app.